# CMAKE: CDR Macro invoked with incorrect arguments for macro named: CDR

Tags: c++, linux, macos, macros, cmake

I am getting this error on my .cmake file trying to run cmake "CDR Macro Invoked Incorrect arguments for macro named: CDR"

I am using exactly the same files on Linux and never had this issue its only occurring on Mac.

I am under the assumption that Linux and OSx has similar configurations.

Any ideas?

Here is the error that i am getting:

> ~/Findsmpq.cmake:20 (CDR):   CDR Macro invoked with incorrect arguments
>   for macro named: CDR Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   ~/cmakemodules/Findsmpq.cmake:166
>   (LIST_INDEX)   CMakeLists.txt:172 (find_package)

here is the code for my .cmake file.

```
   7   #--------------------------------------
   8 # macros related to list
   9 MACRO(CAR var)
   10 SET(${var} ${ARGV1})
   11 ENDMACRO(CAR)
   12 
   13 MACRO(CDR var junk)
   14 SET(${var} ${ARGN})
   15 ENDMACRO(CDR)
   16 
   17 MACRO(LIST_INDEX var index)
   18 SET(list . ${ARGN})
   19 FOREACH(i RANGE 1 ${index})
   20 CDR(list ${list})
   21 ENDFOREACH(i)
   22 CAR(${var} ${list})
   23 ENDMACRO(LIST_INDEX)
   24 
   25 #--------------------------------------
```

and around line 166

```
 134 #--------------------------------------
 135 # to find Qt choose compiler directory
 136 MACRO(QT_COMPILER_LIST result2 curdir2)
 137
 138 FILE(GLOB children2 RELATIVE ${curdir2} ${curdir2}/*)
 139
 140 SET(dirlist2 "")
 141
 142 FOREACH(child2 ${children2})
 143 if(IS_DIRECTORY ${curdir2}/${child2})
 144   if(WIN32)
 145     string(REGEX MATCH "^msvc[_0-9]*" QTCOMP ${child2})  #RE to match MSVC compiled libraries by default
 146   endif(WIN32)
 147   if(UNIX)
 148     string(REGEX MATCH "^gcc[_0-9]*" QTCOMP ${child2})  #RE to match GCC compiled libraries by default (64 bit)
 149   endif(UNIX)
 150
 151  LIST(APPEND dirlist2 ${QTCOMP})
 152 endif()
 153 ENDFOREACH()
 154
 155 SET(${result2} ${dirlist2})
 156
 157 ENDMACRO()
 158
 159 QT_COMPILER_LIST(QT_COMP_DIR ${HOME_DIR}/${QT_PREFIX}/${QT_VER_PREFIX})
 160
 161 message(STATUS "QT_COMP_DIR_LIST :" ${QT_COMP_DIR})
 162
 163 LIST(LENGTH QT_COMP_DIR len)
 164 MESSAGE(STATUS "Number of Qt Compilers:" ${len})
 165
 166 LIST_INDEX(QT_COM_PATH ${len} ${QT_COMP_DIR})   #len specifies which compiler from the list to use
 167 message(STATUS "QT COMP DIR USED:" ${QT_COM_PATH})
 168
 169 if(WIN32)
 170   set(POSSIBLE_PREFIX_PATH  ${HOME_DIR}${QT_PREFIX}/${QT_VER_PREFIX}/${QT_COM_PATH}/lib/cmake)
 171   message(STATUS "QT POSSIBLE_PREFIX_PATH:" ${POSSIBLE_PREFIX_PATH})
 172 endif(WIN32)
 173
 174 if(UNIX)
 175   set(POSSIBLE_PREFIX_PATH ${HOME_DIR}/${QT_PREFIX}/${QT_VER_PREFIX}/${QT_COM_PATH}/lib/cmake)
 176   message(STATUS "QT POSSIBLE_PREFIX_PATH:" ${POSSIBLE_PREFIX_PATH})
 177 endif(UNIX)
 178
 179 find_path(CMAKE_DIR Qt5Config.cmake PATHS ${POSSIBLE_PREFIX_PATH}/Qt5)
 180
 181 endif()
 182
 183 #--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now looking around line 172 in the CMakeLists.txt

```
168 #smpq qt based application
169
170 if(ENABLE_QT_GUI)
171
172  find_package(smpq)
173  if(NOT SMPQ_FOUND)
174    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find SMPQ")
175  endif(NOT SMPQ_FOUND)
176
177  set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${PREFIX_PATH})
178  message(STATUS "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH" ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
179
180  find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core Sql PrintSupport)
181
182  qt5_wrap_cpp(QtProjectLib_hdr_moc ${QtProjectLib_hdr})
183  qt5_wrap_ui(QtProjectLib_ui_uic ${QtProjectLib_ui})
184  qt5_add_resources(QtProjectLib_qrc_rcc ${QtProjectRsc_qrc})
185
186  include_directories (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
187  include_directories (${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
188
189  add_library (QtProjectLib STATIC ${QtProjectLib_src} ${QtProjectLib_hdr_moc} ${QtProjectLib_ui_uic})
190
191  target_link_libraries (QtProjectLib 
192    Qt5::Core 
193    Qt5::Gui 
194    Qt5::Widgets 
195    Qt5::Sql 
196    Qt5::PrintSupport)
197
198  # WIN32 to suppress the console window under Windows
199  add_executable(KTAB_SMP WIN32 ${QtProjectBin_src} ${QtProjectLib_qrc_rcc})
200
201  target_link_libraries (KTAB_SMP
202    QtProjectLib 
203    smp 
204    ${KMODEL_LIBRARY} 
205    ${KUTILS_LIBRARY} 
206    ${SQLITE_LIBRARIES} 
207    ${EFENCE_LIBRARIES}
208    ${TINYXML2_LIBRARIES})
209
210  if(ENABLE_COPY_QT_LIBS AND WIN32)
211    find_package(qtdlls)
212  endif(ENABLE_COPY_QT_LIBS AND WIN32)
213
214 endif (ENABLE_QT_GUI)
```

Comment: In which line is the error triggered? Can give the complete error message including the stack trace? CAR and CDR is very un-CMake-ish. Probably the problem would be solved better in a different way with CMake.

Comment: One of your calls to your `list_index()` is calling `cdr()` with an unescaped null value, which makes it look like it's being called with only one argument.

Comment: If you're trying to find info about your Qt installation, use some introspection instead of trolling your filesystem. CMake [provides options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindQt.html) for Qt3 and Qt4. Qt itself [provides options](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) for Qt5

Comment: @usr1234567 You are right, i admit the code was not very clear i apologize, i just edited the code where it should make more sense including the line numbers.